# Can Pokemon aside from Meowth learn how to talk?

Tags: pokemon

Meowth can speak like a human, but can other Pokemon also be taught to speak?

Comment: I can not remember when I watched this but a slow king was talking to ash. I think it was a movie.

Comment: @Caresten Yes, it's a [movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon:_The_Movie_2000).

Comment: The Gastly that appeared in episode 20 can speak human language.

Comment: i remember slowking talking to ash in the movie the power of one,because i watched it a few days ago.and also lugia talking in the same movie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pokemon can be taught the human language as stated on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talking_Pok%C3%A9mon)

> **All Pokemon in the Pokemon anime, with no exceptions, can understand human speech**. Moreover, judging, for instance, from Larvitar in Hatch Me If You Can, they are able to do this immediately after hatching, without having to learn.
>
> The anime generally does not focus on language problems, so as a result, there is some confusion about Pokémon language and the Ability of Pokémon to understand humans. Although it is obvious that all Pokémon can understand each other, Meowth in the episode Go West Young Meowth once mentions Meowth language, and Jessie in Who's Flying Now? mentions Chimecho language, so it is not clear whether there is a common Pokémon language, or every species has its own.
>
> As far as human language is concerned, Meowth in the same episode was shown learning pronunciation, not the language itself, what implies that all Pokémon have innate knowledge of human language, **so they can understand human speech, and only have to learn how to pronounce its sounds, or be able to establish telepathic contacts to speak.** Despite this, Misty in Whichever Way the Wind Blows once asked Meowth to translate her words to other Pokémon, and **May taught her Bulbasaur the meaning of the word town in Grass Hysteria**. Therefore, this ability of Pokémon is not well-defined in anime canon.

Beside mewtwo and meowth there are several other pokemon that can also speak. They are also listed on the link provided

Comment: I think that list missed something. Didn't Latias turn into human form and speak with Ash?

Comment: @krikara Yup you are right. It can telepathically communicate with people. Don't expect perfection from Bulbapedia lists. People try to maintain it but there is allot of different info to gather and small things like this might be forgotten.

Answer (score 4):

Many Pokemon can talk via telepathy, notably Mewtwo, and (I think) Lapras.

I only recall Meowth being able to vocalize human speech, though. Other Pokemon may be able to be taught individual words.